# Object distortion after ROI Align in Mask R-CNN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, computer-vision, object-detection

In Mask R-CNN, if there are 2 proposed ROIs which cover 2 objects that looks like below:

## #1 A square object

[image]

## #2 A rectangular object

[image]

## So my question is:

1. After ROI Align, is the **#2** feature map transformed from rectangular
   shape to square shape?
2. If so the feature map of both objects are
   very similar, right?
3. So the model will not able to classify 2 classes that are distinguished by their aspect ratio only (for example, Square class and
   Rectangle class), right?
4. So is there any other model that can solve the problem at **3**?

## ROI Align process of rectangle and square

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a sort of hack-y fix, you could add the original dimensions or aspect ratio of the region of interest as a feature sent to the classifier. This should give it information with which to distinguish the two different classes.